# Angular 17: Lazy load standalone component with parameter?

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink, angular-standalone-components

this is my html:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/videos', p.param]">{{ p.title }}</a>
```

this is the code in app.route.ts:

```
{
    path: 'videos/:folder',
    loadComponent: () => import('./pages/application/video/video.component')
      .then(mod => mod.VideoComponent)
  },
```

and this is the code in the VideoComponent (is a standalone component which I try to get value folder:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .subscribe(
        (params: any) => {
          console.log("value params folder:" + params);
          this.folder = params.folder; <--- no value.
        }
      )
  
  }
```

and params.folder has no value.
I google it but I haven't seen any thing.
Is stand alone component support this feature or is there a way to get pass a parameter thru a stand alone component?  Is there any link/example how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, to get detail from activated route you can use `snapshot.paramMap` as below.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.folder = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('folder');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [params.get('folder')](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .subscribe(
        (params: any) => {
          console.log("value params folder:" + params.get('folder'));
          this.folder = params.get('folder');
        }
      }
  }
```

The access method you have used can be done but we need to listen for the `params` property instead of `paramMap`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: any) => {
          console.log("value params folder:" + params);
          this.folder = params.folder;
        }
      }
  }
```